# Integrate: $\int_0^1\frac{\sqrt{1+e^{-x}}}{e^x}\ dx$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, substitution

$$\int_0^1\frac{\sqrt{1+e^{-x}}}{e^x}\ dx$$

Here is my work. Please let me know if my answer is right or acceptable since maybe I failed to simplify it enough.  [image]

Comment: It is a definite integral. 1 and 0 are the bounds.

Comment: You went astray when you brought the expression $\frac{1}{-e^{-x}}$ outside the integral.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Notice, let $1+e^{-x}=u^2\implies -e^{-x}dx=2udu$
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\sqrt{1-e^{-x}}}{e^x}dx=-\int_{0}^{1}(e^{-x})\sqrt{1-e^{-x}}dx$$
$$=-\int_{\sqrt 2}^{\sqrt{1+e^{-1}}}u(2udu) $$ $$=-2\int_{\sqrt 2}^{\sqrt{1+e^{-1}}} u^2du$$ $$=-2\left[\frac{u^3}{3}\right]_{\sqrt 2}^{\sqrt{1+e^{-1}}}$$ 
$$=\frac{2}{3}\left[2\sqrt 2-\left(1+\frac{1}{e}\right)^{3/2}\right]$$

Comment: Why are you letting $1+e^{-x} = u^2$ I don't understand your reasoning. What enables you to square the u?

Comment: We let $1+e^{-x}=u^2\implies -e^{-x}dx=2udu$ so that it can be taken out of square root as $$\sqrt{1+e^{-x}}=\sqrt {u^2}=u$$

Answer (score 7):

You can do this much easier with the substitution $u=1+e^{-x}$. The rest is straightforward.

Comment: It is a definite integral. 1 and 0 are the bounds.

Answer (score 2):

Let $t^2=1+e^{-x}$ for $x \in [0,1]$ Thus, $t \in [1+\frac{1}{e},2]$
$$
\begin{align}
2tdt &=-e^{-x}dx\\
\int_0^1 \frac{\sqrt{1-e^{-x}}}{e^x}dx &=-2\int_2^{1+\frac{1}{e}}t^2dt
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:
We have
$$
\int_{x} \frac{\sqrt{1+e^{-x}}}{e^{x}} = \int_{x} e^{-x}\sqrt{1+e^{-x}}$$$$ = \int_{x}\frac{-2}{3}D(1 + e^{-x})^{3/2} $$$$= \frac{-2}{3}(1 + e^{-x})^{3/2}
$$
Apply chain rule and fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: Missing $dx$ !!

Comment: You have very interesting notation. Where did you learn it? Is there more like it? Does it have any practical benefits over the preexisting notation?

Comment: @Biggs  Thank you. I developed it. For me it would emphasize that the concept of a primitive is independently of that of a definite integral :). Pedagogical benefits, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

Integration is quasi-immediate as $1/e^x=e^{-x}$, which is minus the derivative of the expression under the radical.

Then

$$-\int_0^1\sqrt{1+e^{-x}}\,d(e^{-x})\ dx=-\frac23\left.(1+e^{-x})^{3/2}\right|_0^1=-\frac23((1+e^{-1})^{3/2}-2^{3/2}).$$

---

Even simpler with Zachary Selk's hint:

$$-\int_{u=2}^{1+e^{-1}}\sqrt u\,du.$$

Answer (score 0):

Assume that $t=\sqrt{1+e^{-x}}$ then $$dt=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+e^{-x}}}(-e^{-x})\ dx$$
 $$\int_0^1\frac{\sqrt{1+e^{-x}}}{e^x}\ dx=\int_{\sqrt 2}^{(1+e^{-1})^{1/2}}\frac{\sqrt{1+e^{-x}}}{e^x}\cdot \frac{2\sqrt{1+e^{-x}}}{(-e^{-x})}\ dt$$ 
$$=-2\int_{\sqrt 2}^{(1+e^{-1})^{1/2}}(1+e^{-x})\ dx$$ 
$$=-2\int_{\sqrt 2}^{(1+e^{-1})^{1/2}}t^2\ dt$$ 
$$=-2\left(\frac{t^3}{3}\right)_{\sqrt 2}^{(1+e^{-1})^{1/2}}$$ 
$$=\frac{4\sqrt 2}{3}-\frac{2}{3}\left(1+\frac{1}{e}\right)^{3/2}$$ 
so it is the answer

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting

$$\int_0^1\sqrt{1+e^{-x}}e^{-x}dx=-\int_0^1\sqrt{1+e^{-x}}\,de^{-x}$$ makes the substitution obvious so that you can integrate straight away as

$$\left.-\frac23(1+e^{-x})^{3/2}\right|_0^1=-\frac23((1+e^{-1})^{3/2}-2\sqrt2).$$